# S60 3rd ed Emulator terminates as soon as started in windows 7

Tags: c++, symbian, nokia, carbide

I have installed carbide c++ 2.7 , S60 3rd edition FP2, activePerl on Drive C. carbide c++ detects that the sdk is installed and I can create Symbian OS C++ projects too. When  I build the projects, all the executables are created and when I run the emulator debug, the emulator starts and then after few seconds it terminates. I followed the instruction come with sdk on how to install the sdk on vista( well same should apply for win 7 ryt?).. please help me.. Even I cannot run Hello world program.. :D

Comment: Please help.. i am trying to learn developing apps for symbian.. :(

Comment: Without posting any error code, which should have been thrown into log  (by default EPOCWIND.OUT in the Windows temporary directory ) you won't receive any answer [for another year:].

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem on Windows 7 using SDK Emulators, the issue was that my sound chip was Realtek. If you disable all sound outputs via Sound option from Control Panel and start the Emulator then it will work. After it loads fully just re-enable your sound devices.

That's at least how it worked in my case.